Why does my basic AES256 C# encryption does not match with online encrypters?
I am writing a simple AES implementation and want to use online AES encrypters for verification.
However, when entering the same configuration (same key, ECB mode, 256 key size) I always get a different string output (for both base64 and hex). All online encrypters however ARE outputting the same encrypted string so they are aligned. What am I missing?
Referenced online tools: https://devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption and https://anycript.com/crypto
My code
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace AesApp
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (Aes myAes = Aes.Create())
            {
                myAes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
                myAes.Key = Convert.FromBase64String("gHyP6i8mXqmdFK4rKsKP7EqvzfxwbtyE");

                string plaintext = "test";
                Console.WriteLine($"Plaintext : {plaintext}");

                ICryptoTransform encryptor = myAes.CreateEncryptor();

                using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                        {
                            swEncrypt.Write(plaintext);
                        }

                        byte[] encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                        string encryptedString = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
                        Console.WriteLine($"Encrypted : {encryptedString}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

config:
ECB mode, 
256 key size, 
sample key string = "gHyP6i8mXqmdFK4rKsKP7EqvzfxwbtyE", 
sample plaintext to encrypt = "test",

My output =     "/Ylo00TXuzmuBNYPZy5YOA=="
Online output = "yyO1N4G9uxXJlQ8FLU3KfQ=="


You are decoding the key as base64 which is not the same way online sites like those you have mentioned are decoding, they decode the key as ASCII. If you want to get the same value as online sites you should use the following code:
myAes.Key = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("gHyP6i8mXqmdFK4rKsKP7EqvzfxwbtyE");
By the way, the code you have written is not wrong and it is correct, just your key size is not 256 it is 192-bit.

256 key size means the key is 256 bits (32 bytes) long. Since your sample key string is already 32 bytes long, decoding with base64 will result in the key size becoming 192 bits (24 bytes) long. Therefore, you should use methods such as Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes to convert the key string into a byte array, rather than using FromBase64String.
